# Problem installing ad-hoc app on iphone: "resources have been modified."

Tags: iphone, itunes

I can install an app on my development iPhone compiled with "Debug" configuration using my Ad Hoc provisioning and everything works OK.
But when I build it using "Release" configuration, iTunes says:
The application XXX was not installed on the iPhone "YYYY" because its resources have been modified.

I've never seen this message before. Does anybody know what it means?

Thanks!

Antonio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We finally got rid of the problem. We were trying to include an image for iTunes after creating the build, but when we used this method (http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/itunes-icon-for-ad-hoc-distributions.html) everything went smoothly.

Comment: That doesn't really say how to build beyond adding iTunes artwork though.

Comment: The main issue is adding files to the build after code-signing has occurred. Adding or modifying files breaks the signature and the app won't run on a (non-jailbroken) device.

Answer (score 8):

We had the same problem during our first Beta. Someone on Windows dug in the xxx.app folder then Explorer created a **Thumbs.db** file inside and, **boom**, he got the message *"The application XXX was not installed on the iPhone "YYYY" because its resources have been modified."* when he tried to install.

He had to remove the app from iTunes, deleted all the Thumbs.db from xxx.app and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps someone: In my case, I copied the .app to a network drive, then to my Win7 computer before dragging into iTunes - then it did not work. When I zipped the .app first before copying, and then unzipped it on the other end - it worked. Of course, I have no real idea why....

Comment: That's likely because shipping the app to the network drive dropped all extended properties of the file on the way (for they aren't supported over network filesystems), whereas the ZIP method preserved them... This is common to all Apple-style signed binaries -> they'll break if extended attributes are discarded at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Your debug configuration and your release configuration have some important differences, and release is a lot closer to what ad-hoc should look like. So you first need to duplicate the release configuration and make and call your copy "Ad-Hoc", and make sure you use your ad-hoc provisioning profile with it. Then you need to create a new entitlements file. The new version of Xcode has a cool feature where you can build and archive your app into an ipa file that includes your provisioning profile.

How to do all of this is explained here: http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/23/devsugar-a-better-way-to-share-ad-hoc-builds/

In those instructions, when it tells you to make the entitlements plist file, it says to uncheck get-task-allow in the plist file. When I created the entitlements file, there wasn't a get-task-allow row at all, so I created one, set the type to boolean, and left it unchecked. It worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to avoid wierdness like this is to create an IPA file.  A good step-by-step guide to creating an IPA target in XCode is here:

http://idotcomllc.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/how-to-build-a-ipa-file-from-xcode/

It starts out with an introductory project so search for "Aggregate" to find the point where it starts telling you how to create a new IPA target for build.

Answer (score 1):

I directly upload the app to a server where the windows can also visit. Then compress it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had it, did a clean build and never saw it again.

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete ipa/zip archives (received at the installation end) were the cause for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using a run script to cp -R the .app file to the Payload folder, for some reason when the script copied the file it modified it somehow, if I used finder and manually copied the .app file into the payload folder and manually zipped the .ipa file it worked fine. I tested it several times using codesign -v to verify the .app file. it always through the error after a build and the run script. but no error when I would copy the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the .Double files being added to every directory on a shared network drive. We are primarily a Windows environment, and the Mac was saving .Double file on the drive, in every directory.

Literally, to fix the issue referenced above, I simply deleted the .Double files in every directory (of the app being copied to iTunes) and it fixed it.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked to test some apps and for some reason was the only one on my team getting this this error. I am working on an XP. All the apps we are testing use the same provisioning file yet some would sync while others would not. Not sure what fixed it but I did go into my **My Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications** folder, deleted the existing .ipa file for the app I was trying to sync and it seemed to sync fine after. It might not be the answer to your problem but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with asstes on a Mac, or have versioned content, I had the same problem with .DS_Store files and hidden .git folders. Once deleted from assets, problem gone. It might be an issue with hidden files.